# what does mean this part of paragraph? ( from c#4.0 Herbert schildt )

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

The use of ref and out is not limited to the passing of value types. They can also be used
when a reference is passed. When ref or out modifies a reference, it causes the reference,
itself, to be passed by reference. This allows a method to change what object the reference
refers to.

---

what does mean this part ?

When ref or out modifies a reference, it causes the reference,
 itself, to be passed by reference. This allows a method to change what object the reference
 refers to.

Answer (score 2):

It means that by using `ref` you can change which object a variable points to, not only the contents of the object.

Let's say that you have a method with a `ref` parameter, that replaces an object:

```
public static void Change(ref StringBuilder str) {
   str.Append("-end-");
   str = new StringBuilder();
   str.Append("-start-");
}
```

When you call it, it will change the variable that you call it with:

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder b = a; // copy the reference
a.Append("begin");

// variables a and b point to the same object:

Console.WriteLine(a); // "begin"
Console.WriteLine(b); // "begin"

Change(b);

// now the variable b has changed

Console.WriteLine(a); // "begin-end-"
Console.WriteLine(b); // "-start-"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
MyClass myObject = null;
InitializeIfRequired(ref myObject);
// myObject is initialized
...

private void InitializeIfRequired(ref MyClass referenceToInitialize)
{
    if (referenceToInitialize == null)
    {
        referenceToInitialize = new MyClass();
    }
}
```